# Capturing Crash logs

Tags: android, crashlytics

I am writing a custom UncaughtExceptionHandler to end the app gracefully. For collecting crash logs, I am using Crashlytics. The objective is to

1. gather the crash logs in the custom Uncaughtexception handler.
2. Send the crash logs to Crashlytics server.
3. Restart the app without showing "Force Close" dialog.

To achieve that I have written the following code which seems to catch the UncaughtExceptions but it's not sending the off to the Crashlytics server.

public class MyApplication extends Application{

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mUEHandler;
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler mDefaultUEHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

    mDefaultUEHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    mUEHandler = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
            reEmergeFromCrash();
            Crashlytics.logException(e);
        }
    };

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(mUEHandler);

    throw new RuntimeException("hello");
}
}
```

What am doing wrong? How can I send the caught crash logs to Crashlytics.

Comment: What will this do?

Comment: Besides there is no API called CrashManager

Comment: Just add Fabrics API and follow the steps given in the tutorial. You don't need to add much of a code. I confused Crashlytics with Fabric. Sorry for that.

Comment: Where can I find the fabric api? Can you point me to a sample app/tutorial which implements this method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Crashlytics.logException() does record your exceptions that you have caught, however to put less strain on the app's resources, Fabric has designed Crashlytics to send the recorded exceptions off to the server the next time you open the app.